# Is there a way in Flutter to split a long ListView into multiple "pages"?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, listview, navigation

I'm a beginner in coding and I'm trying to create an app to practice and learning dart and flutter.

My app has a page with a long ListView (700 items) and I want to make some sort of "page navigator" to split the ListView in 7 (100 items per page).
I know about the pagination ListView but I don't link the result.
I'm sorry for my poor vocabulary on explaining what I want to do, here's an example

[Example of "pages navigator"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q94L.jpg)

Ultimately, I want that all my items in this "splitted ListView" could be filterable by a search bar.

Here's my **list.dart** code so far:

```
class SongList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _buildListView(context),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildListView(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 700,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        final count = index + 1;

        return new ListTile(
          leading: new CircleAvatar(
            child: new Text(
              "$count",
              style: TextStyle(color: kBackgroundColor),
            ),
            backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
          ),
          title: new Text("Song #$count"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SongDetail(index),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Divider();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: pageView can do that depends on how you use it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment @ArbiterChil !
Can you elaborate that? I don't know how to do that :(

It is important to me that every item should be filterable with a single searchbar, plus I don't want to navigate through by swiping my screens, I want to navigate "the old-fashioned way" by tapping on page numbers.

Comment: PageView can make many pages you want depends on how many you want or just getting the lenght of a result then inside of it will be you widget or cards want to show but you should limit it since you want old fashioned way this will be a long discussion do you have discord? or something so if i can lead it to you
Arbiterchil#9021 my discord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: I made it!

I discovered this package which is amazing!
https://pub.dev/packages/number_paginator

So I updated the code from below and replaced the CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl with the NumberPaginator widget.

Here the code:

```
              child: NumberPaginator(
                numberPages: 7,
                onPageChange: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentPage = index;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

The packages provide even some properties in order to customize the colors and shape of the page indicators.

---

### Old solution

I hope this will be helpful for someone. Please note that I'm still a learner and if somethig in this code is off and might be better comment and add your contribution.

I didn't find any native "paging widget" in Flutter so I ended up using **CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl** for the "paging widget" and **CupertinoUserInterfaceLevel** for the "body" of the segments/pages.

My song list is provided by a database helper and some queries, I dediced to split the my 700 items list in 7 queries and call them according to the selected segment/page indicator.

This is my code with some useful comments.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'; // Required in order to use Cupertino Widgets

import '/assets/data/queries.dart'; // My queries are in another dart file
import '/assets/data/db_tables.dart';

import 'songs_detail.dart';

class SongsBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SongsBodyState createState() => _SongsBodyState();
}

class _SongsBodyState extends State<SongsBody> {
  // Change this in order to edit the segment/paging widget, you can put text and icons
  final Map<int, Widget> children = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text('1'),
    1: Text('2'),
    2: Text('3'),
    3: Text('4'),
    4: Text('5'),
    5: Text('6'),
    6: Text('7'),
  };

  // Change this to set the initial segment/page
  int currentSegment = 0;

  // This is required to update the state when you tap on another segment/page
  void onValueChanged(newValue) {
    setState(() {
      currentSegment = newValue;
    });
  }

  // My queries from queries.dart are called here and used later in the code
  final List<Future<List?>> _query = [
    QueryCtr().getSongsFrom1To100(),
    QueryCtr().getSongsFrom101To200(),
    QueryCtr().getSongsFrom201To300(),
    QueryCtr().getSongsFrom301To400(),
    QueryCtr().getSongsFrom401To500(),
    QueryCtr().getSongsFrom501To600(),
    QueryCtr().getSongsFrom601To700(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // This is the segment control widget (our "paging" widget)
        CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl<int>(
          children: children,
          onValueChanged: onValueChanged,
          groupValue: currentSegment,
        ),
        const Divider(),
        // This is the "body" of our segment/page
        CupertinoUserInterfaceLevel(
          data: CupertinoUserInterfaceLevelData.base,
          // My listview is now called with a future builder because I'm getting the data from my database
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return FutureBuilder<List?>(
                // This is the interesting part: I update only the query according to the selected segment
                future: _query[currentSegment],
                initialData: const [],
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.hasData
                  // If there is some data show them in a listview wrapped in expanded
                      ? Expanded(
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                              // Here I decided to code a separate widget to build the rows of my listview
                              return _buildRow(snapshot.data![i]);
                            },
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return const Divider();
                            },
                          ),
                        ) 
                  // If there is no data return a progress indicator
                      : const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(Raccolta get) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(
          get.songId.toString(),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(get.songTitle),
      trailing: const Icon(
        Icons.navigate_next,
        color: somecolor,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        int songId = get.songId;
        String songTitle = get.songTitle;
        String songText = get.songText;
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return SongsDetail(songId, songTitle, songText);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```